# Assign value to int in one method, next method value is changed to -89xxxxxxxxx

Tags: c++

```
class test
{
    public:
        int a;
        void init(int _a);
        void read(void);
}
```

I have this simple program. From another class I init the test object with some value of "_a".

```
void init(int _a){
    a = _a;
}
```

Init:

```
testObject.init(3);
```

But when I enter "read()", the value of a = -858993460.
I understand that something is wrong ( :)   ). That it might be a pointer that is not used anymore. But. When I write "a = _a", shouldn't the VALUE of a be a copy of value of _a?

```
void read(void){
    printf("a-value %d \n" , a);
}
```

How do I copy the value of _a to a, so that a doesnt change when _a change?

Comment: Might want to include the code for `read` as well since the problem might originate there. Right now there is no return value for `read` so we have no clue what it's really trying to do.

Comment: Show how you call `init` and `test`. Are you sure it's the same object?

Comment: what does main look like?  where are these getting called from.

Comment: Please show us the redacted source. I don't see any problems with the code above, except for `init` that should be `test::init` in the second snippet.

Comment: Given your code, it's works fine on my machine (g++ 4.7).

Comment: This is not related, but is there a reason why you prefer `init()` to a constructor?

Comment: "I understand that something is wrong ( :) ). That it might be a pointer that is not used anymore. " *None* of this code presented here has pointers used *at all*. Therefore I find it highly non-coincidental that you included this observation in your self-assessment. And it consequently lends tremendous fuel to the fire that whatever your problem is (and it now sounds memory-mgmt related), it is in the code you're **not** sharing with us here.

Comment: Post a minimal program that reproduces the issue. Also not related, the underscore is usually used for the member variables and not for the parameters. And a function doing `printf` is usually a `write` and not a `read`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The code is huge and the object ripple through multiple objects. Without testing i wrote this simple code. As some of you said the object were never initiated. The chains of inits broke. Thanks everyone for helping me to find where to look :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My psychic debugging sense tells me that either `a` is not actually getting set, or you're not actually setting the `a` that you think you're setting.

Maybe you're not really calling `init` before you call `read`, or maybe you're calling them on different instances of `test`

Normally when you get a jumbled number like that, it's a telltale sign of a "garbage" number that has not been initialized.